# Looking for a more elegant way of writing this

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks essentially like this:

```
​<table id="mytable">
   <tbody>
       <tr id="tempRowID">
           <td class="delete"> <img src="myImage.png" /> </td>
       </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

I need to put the table ID into a variable when the img is clicked.  This function is working, but seems ugly with all the parent() jumps:

```
$(document).on('click', 'table td', function () {

    var currentTable = $(this).parent().parent().parent().attr("id");

});
```

I have tried:

```
    var currentTable = $(this).eq(3).attr("id");
    var currentTable = $(this).find("table").attr("id");
```

Any advice?

Comment: `$(this).closest('table').attr('id')`

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: Probably more a question for codereview rather than SO...

Comment: Let the flood of "closest" answers/comments begin!

Comment: SOoo, what your saying is I should use .closest?   Hey look at that, it worked!  Good deal, thanks.... everyone.  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the closest ancestor that is a `table`.

```
var currentTable = $(this).closest("table").attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

How about using [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `.closest()` method

```
var currentTable = $(this).closest('table').attr("id");
```